# How to convert string to hours in dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have string like "080000000000" mean 08.00 AM. So, i'm using format DateFormat('jm');

I tried to substring 4 first string convert using DateTime.parse but throws an exception.

How to achieve the given string to  08.00 AM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are only Dealing with

> Time of the Day

- You can use - [TimeOfDay class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TimeOfDay-class.html)

Code :

```
String myVal = "080000000000";

String myHour = myVal.substring(0, 2);
String myMin = myVal.substring(2, 4);

TimeOfDay releaseTime = TimeOfDay(hour: int.parse(myHour), minute: int.parse(myMin));
print(releaseTime.format(context)); // 8:00 AM
```

Also for accepted string for

```
DateTime parse (
String formattedString
)
```

you can check Examples of accepted strings: - https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html

For 24-hours format - add:

```
MaterialApp(
      builder: (context, child) =>
          MediaQuery(data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: true), child: child),
```

Comment: but in sample if you fill hours = 15, the output is 3:00pm. I tried in my machine it's not converted to 24 hours format.

Comment: updated the answer please check @antonovria   ref - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52012115/10269042