# Time validation error on input when setting hour in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-form-builder

Hi everyone I have some troubles with Flutter [`FormBuilderDateTimePicker`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder)

My problem is that when I set the value manually (with a keyboard not using graphical draggable 'arrows' offered by the widget) I get the validation error every time the **hour** value is between 12 and 00.

For example, if I set 12:30 the value will be accepted, but if I change the hour to 16:30 it will display a validation error message. Below you can find a graphical representation of my case.

[image]
[image]

Here is how I set my `FormBuilderTimePicker` widget

```
    FormBuilderDateTimePicker(
         name: 'fieldname',
         initialValue: DateTime.now(),
         initialDate: DateTime.now(),
         initialEntryMode: DatePickerEntryMode.input,
         alwaysUse24HourFormat: true,
         onChanged: (value) => mayValue = ,
         format: DateFormat.yMMMMd('it_IT').add_Hm(),
         timePickerInitialEntryMode: TimePickerEntryMode.input,
       )
```

The other input type is working fine, but I would like to keep them both
[image]

Comment: Take a look to this issue and related https://github.com/danvick/flutter_form_builder/issues/826

Comment: @Nagual well I hoped someone else tryed it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `flutter_form_builder: ^7.3.1` source code, `alwaysUse24HourFormat` has not being used. As matias-de-andrea mention on [git issue](https://github.com/danvick/flutter_form_builder/issues/826) which is still open.

To make it work, they override the `transitionBuilder` in order to provide 24h format on `showTimePicker` context.

```dart
transitionBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
    return MediaQuery(
      data: MediaQuery.of(context)
          .copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: true),
      child: child!,
    );
  },
```

You can check [How to use 24 hour clock when invoking showTimePicker() in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52002388/10157127) and they've discussed more about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable hour/minute textfield height decreasing by wrapping the builder of timer picker with a new `Theme` and setting `errorStyle` of `inputDecorationTheme` to 0.

```
              TimeOfDay? timeOfDay = await showTimePicker(
                context: context,
                initialTime: _toTime,
                initialEntryMode: TimePickerEntryMode.inputOnly,
                hourLabelText: '',
                minuteLabelText: '',
                helpText: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.enterTime,
                confirmText: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.save,
                builder: (context, child) {
                  return Theme(
                    data: theme.copyWith(
                      inputDecorationTheme:
                          theme.inputDecorationTheme.copyWith(
                        errorStyle: const TextStyle(height: 0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: child!,
                  );
                },
              );
```